# How best to handle existing database column mappings with an Entity Framework Code First model class manually?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I am building an EF Code First driven application using an existing MSSQL database. I really want to avoid having to use any power tools or wizard based auto-code generation utilities to build my model and dbcontext, as we will need total control over code gen.

My question is, when I build my models (which will end up as dbset() properties in my context), how should I approach the existing SQL columns in my models? Am I required to add a property to my model classes for every db column that is set to "Not Nullable" in the database? Will EF know what to do if I leave out some properties in my model, that corresponding to db columns? Just not sure how this should all work out and am having a bit of trouble finding resources with a direct answer to CF model to existing db field mappings. Does someone have information that would help clarify this process?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend using EF Power Tools to reverse engineer your existing database into POCO classes if only to learn some tips/tricks on how to manually code them yourself. I was able to get a decent grasp on how to use the Fluent API by reverse engineering one of our production databases.

Comment: Also, there are several ways to do what you want to do. I like the Fluent API because I think it ends up being more clean/easy to maintain (your model and the specifics about it's implementation are seperated). A lot of other people like Data Annotations because they're much easier to pick up/use and because they're NOT seperated from the model.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the only way I have worked with EF so far and have had no problems. EF will write null values to the DB if the property on your object is null. Also, all of your columns do not need to be represented in your Entity (although obviously all required columns need to be there, or have default values at the DB level if you want to do inserts). I think the reason it is hard to find some info on this these types of questions is this is the stuff ORMs just do, and do well. I would suggest just trying to create and use your first entities, and see what problems you encounter. It will likely be a lot easier than it seems from where you stand now.

Comment: Great, thank you. I will generate the entities with Entity Datamodel, then work from there in CF. Seems like its a safe route for EF against existing db's.

Comment: Columns that are non-nullable with throw an exception.  Also, any changes made to the db structure outside of EF will not be propagated.  Unless the db is pure code first, IMO its best practice to generate a model first.

Comment: I have mapped an object in a throwaway conversion app where I did not define properties for non-nullable columns and was able to load the objects - unless I am mistaken on the DB setup from that project. If you are sure I am wrong I will have to go dig that out and try and figure out what my misunderstanding is... this would be good to have clear.

Comment: @Maess, by generating an Entity DataModel from VS, am I going to be breaking the pure CF approach? Sorry if my questions are noob, im still trying to get a handle on this.

Comment: @Maess I just added a new, not null, column to an existing DB table in my project and gave it a default value. Still able to load and use this object with no code changes to my entities, etc.

Comment: @Matthew this assumes that devs are in total control of the database.  Also, what if there are columns in the existing tables that are non-null no default?  It's on a save that you will get exceptions, the entities will read just fine.

Comment: @Maess I tested that as well, and I was correct in my answer above, everything will continue to work until you attempt to save a new object with no value for that column (as your entity has no knowledge of the column). Further I also tested an update, which also works fine as expected. Basically, if there are non-nullable columns in your DB that the entity is not aware of with no default defined, you are only limited by an inability to insert, which will cause an exception.

Comment: @Matthew The reason for the downvote is because it's a rather naive and unhelpful answer. I'm of the opinion that just diving in and tinkering around is the best way to learn this stuff too but it's not exactly helpful when you're trying to learn specifics. Especially if the plan isn't just to tinker/learn but to actually build out code that's going to be used in production. There's a lot that can go wrong if you're trying to map things to an existing database with EF and you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hybrid approach, start with a data first model, and then add your new entities using a code-first approach.

EF will throw an exception if the entity does not match the database entity that it is mapped to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So the EF model class will need a direct property-to-db column mapping for each column, regardless of its nullable status?

Comment: Yes, and the nullable status must match, if a column does not allow nulls your entity can not allow nulls.

Comment: Ok, got it. It looks like it may be best to generate an edmx model in this case, to save time.. The db has lots of large tables and it would take a good amount of time to write properties for each column in this case. Would you recommend an EF Datamodel edmx or would another approach be better, like DBContext Generator 5 for instance?

Comment: DbContext generator for sure.